# Teeter game using motion sensor

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, gyroscope, core-motion

I'm relatively new to SpriteKit and I'm looking to make a game similar to Teeter so I can develop my personal knowledge. After spending a couple of days searching around the web I could not find any tutorials that teach you how to use iPhones motion sensors When the device is tilted) so I gave up and turned to Stack. More specific, I want to really know if there's away to maybe use CoreMotion framework together with SpriteKit as one. If not, what is "the best solution or approach" to developing a game such as Teeter that runs on iOS devices without using third party game engines?

Comment: do you mean like when the device is tilted?

Comment: Hi @Lucas yeah thats what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can use Core Motion:

```
@import CoreMotion;
```

Here's an example implementation of accelerometer readings - declare an instance variable:

```
CMMotionManager *_myMotionManager;
```

Initial setup as you initialise your scene:

```
_myMotionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
_myMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2; // tweak the sensitivity of intervals
[_myMotionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
```

This is how to gather accelerometer data on the Y axis (there are three: X, Y, Z) - put this in the update method of your Sprite Kit game:

```
float yAcceleration = _myMotionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
NSLog(@"y axis acceleration data: %f", yAcceleration);
```

Make sure you `[_myMotionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];` when they're no longer needed.

If you need gyroscope data, the approach is very similar - here, you'd start gyro updates and use  `_myMotionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.y` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct with your line of thinking.  Instead of game objects responding to changes from touches it would be from changes in the gyroscope, which can be accessed through CoreMotion.

Not really sure what more you would want to know, just make sure to setup the update of the gyroscope info to be faster if the default report speed seems laggy with your app. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It sounds to me like I need to work out how to implement gyroscope methods. I shall be looking around to see if I can find some good documentation or tutorials regarding gyroscope.